# Class vector of objects from another class

Tags: c++, oop

I am writing code to simulate a robot moving around a competition board, picking up blocks and maneuvering around. At the moment, I have 2 classes in separate files (there are actually like 5 or 6, but I only need to learn this for 1): robot.h and block.h. Here is a sample of my code:

```
//block.h
namespace rmas{
  class Block{
    //attributes of block
  };
}

//robot.h
namespace rmas{ //Robot Movement Algorithm Simulator
  class Robot{
    vector<Block> blocks_on_robot;
  };
}
```

I keep getting the error or error-type in the vector in the robot class. What I am trying to do is have an environment create the blocks and then load them onto the map. As the robot picks those blocks up, the block objects are loaded into the vector blocks_on_robot. Whenever the robot puts the blocks on the platform, the block objects would be moved to a vector in the platform class.

I am kind of at a loss on how (or where) to create these storage vectors, (I think i can just use the vector index to pass the objects around later). I realize this is kind of a confusing question. I could use an external function to handle everything remotely, but this seems like something I should be able to do and that solution gets clunky with 30 or 40 things to manage (which is what it will be eventually). I am self taught, so often I just don't know where to look for answers. I appreciate any all help I can get!

Comment: Did you `#include "block.h"` in `robot.h`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Please paste the exact error message. Next, it would be very helpful if you can manage to either reduce your real code or expand this summary code, to get something short we can actually copy and paste to get that same error message (see [mre]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#include` the `"block.h"` in your `robot.h` file, so it should look like this:

```
#include <vector>

#include "block.h"

namespace rmas {

class Robot {
    std::vector<Block> blocks_on_robot;
};

}
```

Here's a small complete working example: https://repl.it/repls/PromotedInfantileMathematics
Of course in your actual project you should just have the declarations of the `Block` and `Robot` constructors in the header files and move the definitions to `block.cpp` and `robot.cpp` respectively.

Comment: This one fixed my problem. I feel like I tried that at some point, but its working now so it might be better not to ask any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
//block.h
namespace rmas{
  class Block{
    //attributes of block
  };
}

//robot.h
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
namespace rmas{ //Robot Movement Algorithm Simulator
  class Robot{
    vector<Block> blocks_on_robot;
  };
}
```

Comment: This will not compile.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are not as useful as those that include an explanation of how the code answers the question.